# Entity Reference, references dont display

Tags: 7, nodes, entities

I have an article content type, and this article can be assigned to a topic content type. I have created a bunch of articles and topics, and this worked before. But for some reason, all of the sudden no more topics show up when editing an article content-type.

I was in the progress of adding a 'featured' story field with entity reference to the topic. This might have confused the database? Anyway, can I roll back without redo-ing everything and get this two sided relationship working?

** edit **

It seems that the old references still exist in the database as well, but dont show up as options in the article content-type add/edit forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, found it. I had changed the language for my user session on the frontend.  Content wasn't yet populated in that langauge, therefore it didn't display.